# If called by bash script - does PHP script that slept remember it's variables?

Tags: php, bash, sleep

I've got a PHP script that runs from bash/command line. It's passed variables that I pickup with $argv[x] - question is, if I haven't got some data yet, I want the script to sleep and try again in 10 seconds.

If I do

`if(!empty($filePlease)) { sleep(10); }`

Once it wakes up and tries again, does it maintain the argv's passed?

Comment: How are you re-running your script?

Comment: sleep() just relinquishes the cpu and schedules a wakeup call for 10 seconds from now. Nothing will be forgotten and execution will continue as before, just 10 seconds later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the execution of the script is not terminated, the state (including variables) is maintained.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as long as your PHP script doesn't exit, you will maintain the arguments passed in.